# Sound doesn't work on ASUS VH242H Monitor

Tags: windows, macbook, display, audio

Hi I recently bought this monitor but the sound doesn't seem to be working.  I'm using it with my Macbook Pro.  The sound works fine in OS X but doesn't work in Windows 7.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is the driver for the audio installed in Windows?  (That is to say, you get sound in Windows on OTHER devices plugged into the same port?)  If this is over HDMI, you may need to explicitly install that with the video driver package.

Comment: I can get sound from my laptop speakers and from headphones I plug in.  It is not over HDMI it is simply an audio cable connected to my monitor which has speakers..

Comment: If it's the same cable and the same port as the headphones, I'm clueless.  It shouldn't need manual switching if you can get other things to work over that port.